# Update a single element in an xml document

Tags: java, ruby, xml

Is it possible to parse and then modify a single element in an XML document?

I'm currently writing a script in ruby which needs to modify a value (specified by xpath) in an xml file. I'm currently using the REXML library to do this:

```
xmldocument = Document.new(File.new(filename))
property = XPath.first(xmldocument, "/parent/element/property")
property.text = "New property value"
puts xmldocument
```

Where the input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <element>
        <property>Old property value</property>
        <verbose />
    </element>
    ...
    (more elements here)
    ...
</parent>
```

And the output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
    <element>
        <property>New property value</property>
        <verbose/>
    </element>
    ...
    (more elements here)
    ...
</parent>
```

You should notice that the output xml is slightly reformatted and more than my desired change are made. For example the tag `<verbose />` is changed to `<verbose/>` and double quotes are replaced with single quotes in the first line.

What is the best way to modify just a given element of an xml file and leave the rest of the file intact? Ideally, there is a solution for Ruby but I'd love to know the solution in other languages such as Java.

Comment: Java has a ton of API's and libraries that let you read-modify-write an XML file, but I don't know any that will preserve such low-level details like single/double quoting of attribute values and white space before self-closing tags. AFAIK you'd have to use an XML processor to locate the character offsets in the file between which you want to replace the value and then separately modify those parts as if the file were plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the Saxon library should accomplish everything you're looking for:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/